# How can a PHP backend ensure the response arrived at the client successfully?

Tags: php, rest, kotlin, networking, response

I have a frontend (written in Kotlin) and a backend in PHP.
In my use case the frontend sends a request to the backend with it´s service request and then the backend answers. Since every request (can) cost(s) the user quite a lot, it should be ensured, that he always receives the response and if it is not successfully delivered (e.g. he´s losing connection), it is retried and marked as not yet delivered on multiple failures.
So my question is now, is there any way to find out in the backend, if a message successfully arrived at the frontend? (And in best case also when)
In theory it should be possible to find out, since the TCP protocol needs to send an ACK for every successful packet. But I have no idea how to do this, since the response of the PHP backend works with a simple `echo json_encode(data)`.
Or do I need to send an additional request to the server "I have received your response"?

Comment: maybe this could help https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php

Comment: Are you using http? I would assume so. You can check if the connection is aborted sure, but the server then has no way to push data to the client side, unless you have a separate channel such as push notifications or websockets available for that. In standard HTTP a server cannot pro-actively send to a client, it can only respond to requests

Comment: Related: The Two Generals Problem - https://youtu.be/IP-rGJKSZ3s

Comment: TCP provides a reliable transmission between peers, and takes care of retransmitting dropped packets, ensuring packets arrive in order, etc. You shouldn't need to worry about that aspect of communications. If your real concern is that an action should be performed once and shouldn't be repeated then you should read up on [idempotency](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).

Comment: Instead of investing into debugging the protocol I would implement a specific "received" acknowledgement in the client that is sent once the response has been received, validated and processed. This is often done in a three-stroke-pattern: first request triggers the generation of the payload and delivers back a unique ID, second request fetches the payload that has been prepared as a result of the first request and the third request acknowledges and closes the session, allowing the server to free the payload.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular But TCP can´t reliably finish the transmission, if the connection is gone in the middle of transmission for multiple hours. Which can easily happen, where the application is used. (Upcountry Burundi)

Comment: If TCP can't be relied upon then nothing you implement using it can be relied upon. You come back to the Two Generals and idempotency.